# MongoDB returning "Email has already been used" when document is not in collection

Tags: mongodb, express

I am very new to MongoDB and I am testing my register/user route to try to create a new user.  I'm using Postman.  When I try to create the new user, I am getting the error that I set if the user already exists.  However this is a new user and the document is not in the collection.  Please could someone tell me where I am going wrong.

```
//Creating a new user
adminRouter.post('/register/user', async(req, res)=>{
    const {email, password, company, role, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
    console.log('email for new user: ', email);

    //check if username already exists
    const takenEmail = await Users.find({email: email});
    
    if (takenEmail) {
        res.status(400).json({message: "Email has already been used"})
    } else {
        const hashedPW = await bcrypt.hash(password,saltRounds);
        await Users.create({
            email: email,
            password: hashedPW,
            company: company,
            role:  role,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            
        });
        
        res.json({message: `SUCCESS: User ${email} created.`});
    }
    
});
```

Comment: The example code is missing the mongo client setup.  Please include enough code in your example so that it can be copied and tested/executed.

Comment: Thanks @barrypicker.  I will remember to do so next time (still pretty new to Stack Overflow).  As you will see form my recent post I managed to solve my problem by using .findOne() rather than .find();  Thank you for jumping on my query though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my own problem by using the .findOne() method rather than .find() when checking whether the user already exists.

```
adminRouter.post('/register/user', async(req, res)=>{
    const {email, password, company, role, firstName, lastName } = req.body;
    console.log('email for new user: ', email);

    //check if username already exists
    const takenEmail = await Users.findOne({email: email});
    if (takenEmail) {
        res.status(409).json({message: "Email has already been used"})
    } else {
        const hashedPW = await bcrypt.hash(password,saltRounds);
        await Users.create({
            email: email,
            password: hashedPW,
            company: company,
            role:  role,
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName
        });
        
        res.status(201).json({message: `SUCCESS: User ${email} created.`});
    }
    
});
```